# Is there a way to improve CodeNarc performance?

Tags: performance, groovy, gradle, codenarc

Recently after upgrading to CodeNarc version 0.23 and Gradle to version 2.4 we've noticed that there is huge impact on a build time.

Since the versions upgrade CodeNarc task started to fail quite often with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` as well.

I may add that the build is executed on fairly small codebase. Less than 20 source files, average up to 50 lines.

With CodeNarc 0.21 and Gradle 2.2.x it was less of an issue.

How the performance may be optimized and what's the proper way of setting bigger max PermGen space for CodeNarc? Is $GRADLE_OPTS propagated into forked CodeNarc process? Results of may experiments were rather indeterministic, unfortunately.

Comment: What JVM version are you building on?

Comment: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08)

Comment: same here, small codebase, upgrade 0.21 > 0.24 leads to OOME